Сортировка коллекции в С#, индексы сравниваемых элементов
Пытаюсь отсортировать List<Action> actionsList по значению набора полей, GetActionPriority возвращает совокупный "вес" набора:
actionsList.Sort((Action first, Action second) =>
    GetActionPriority(first).CompareTo(GetActionPriority(second)));

но при этом - хотелось бы, чтобы при сортировке, элементы, добавленные в коллекцию позже (т.е. имеющие большее значение индекса в коллекции) не оказались в результате ближе к началу коллекции. Как бы actionsList.OrderBy(x=>GetActionPriority(x)).ThenOrderBy(<начальный индекс элемента в коллекции>). Пока не могу сообразить, как это сделать не вводя дополнительного параметра в Action, надеюсь на вашу помощь
p.s. нет уверенности, что встроенный алгоритм без дополнительных ограничений не изменит порядок элементов по первоначальному индексу

Согласно документации, метод List.Sort реализует нестабильную (unstable) сортировку, т. е. порядок элементов не гарантируется. Если нужна стабильная (stable) сортировка, с сохранением порядка элементов, то используйте метод OrderBy

А, прочитал полностью. То есть вопрос именно в том, как сохранить стабильность в List.Sort? Не используя OrderBy?

@AlexanderPetrov, скорее - вопрос в том, как привязаться к начальным индексам элементов коллекции. То, что приходит в голову, какое-то очень корявое

Вводить дополнительный параметр в Action необязательно, если воспользоваться анонимным типом как оберткой и методом Select.
var sortedActionsList = actionsList
    .Select((action, index) => new { Action = action, Index = index }) // Добавляем исходные индексы
    .OrderBy(x => GetActionPriority(x.Action))                          // Сортировка по приоритету
    .ThenBy(x => x.Index)                                               // Сортировка по исходному индексу для сохранения порядка
    .Select(x => x.Action)                                              // Возвращаем только элементы списка
    .ToList();


благодарю, всё время вылетает из головы неявный index
